# Adding github library license to Android project

Tags: android, android-studio, github

I'm working on a project on android studio in which I've used a library from GitHub. It's a licensed library so I need to add the license in my project. But I don't know how to add it, where to write the license code, what to write as a license. Can anyone help me in the same.

Comment: check this https://developers.google.com/android/guides/opensource